# An error occurred while trying to call the requested method validateAssets. (1272)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store, app-store-connect

When I tried to submit an App to Itunes Connect I got the following error.

```
App Store Connect Operation Error

An error occurred while trying to call the requested method validateAssets. (1272)
```

[image: error]

Any suggestions on what I need to change to be able to submit my app?

Comment: Same error today. Sometimes its "validateMetadata. (1272)"

Comment: Same is happening for me, just now... Is this a App Store Connect outage?

Comment: same error with validateMetadata (1272). how to fixe it?

Comment: Same story, looking for a fix

Comment: Nothing new yet, Apple System status says there is an outage.

Comment: The resurrection of the issue! https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/issues/19572

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Looks like theres an apple developer outage: https://developer.apple.com/system-status/

Answer (score 2):

Try multiple times, I've managed to upload build right now in less then 100 attempts xD

Comment: Nvm, even after "successful" upload the build is not visible on Appstore Connect even as "Processing", so it was just a partial victory. Best thing is to give up and wait for Apple to fix problems :/

Comment: Came here to say this! After it's showing as green tick successful in Organizer, i actually can't see it in App Store connect! So yeah, bugger.

Comment: my new version finally showed up... seems like it's resolved? as far as i can see it so far